# Can someone help how to create graph client using token of IAuthenticationResult (msal4j)

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-msal, adal, clientcredential

Using ADAL library in Java , I created token (using client credential provider) ,the resulted token is **TokenCredentialAuthProvider** which is of **IAuthenticationProvider** type. this token i was able to use to create a graph client.

But as i want to migrate from ADAL to MSAL ,I tried creating a token using MSAL4j (java) (using client credential provider) and the resulted token was of the form **IAuthenticationResult** , which i cant use to create Graph client as it requires an instance of **IAuthenticationProvider**.

how to create graph client using token of the form **IAuthenticationResult (msal4j)**

Answer (score 0):

MS Graph clients creation require an instance of [IAuthenticationProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.graph.authentication.iauthenticationprovider?view=graph-core-java). Several built-in providers and samples are available in [Choose a Microsoft Graph authentication provider based on scenario](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?tabs=Java). If you already posses an token you can create your own class/implementation and return the token returned by [IAuthenticationResult.getAccessToken()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.identity.client.iauthenticationresult?view=azure-java-stable#com-microsoft-identity-client-iauthenticationresult-getaccesstoken()) from within the [getAuthorizationTokenAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.microsoft.graph.authentication.iauthenticationprovider?view=graph-core-java#com-microsoft-graph-authentication-iauthenticationprovider-getauthorizationtokenasync(java-net-url)) method.

E.g.

```java
// MyAuthenticationProvider.java
package com.example;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;

public class MyAuthenticationProvider implements IAuthenticationProvider {

    private CompletableFuture<String> accessTokenFuture;

    public MyAuthenticationProvider(String accessToken) {
        this.accessTokenFuture = new CompletableFuture<>();
        this.accessTokenFuture.complete(accessToken);
    }

    @Override
    public CompletableFuture<String> getAuthorizationTokenAsync(URL requestUrl) {
        return this.accessTokenFuture;
    }

}

// App.java
package com.example;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.microsoft.graph.authentication.IAuthenticationProvider;
import com.microsoft.graph.models.User;
import com.microsoft.graph.requests.GraphServiceClient;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String msalAccessToken = args[0];

        final IAuthenticationProvider auth = new MyAuthenticationProvider(msalAccessToken);

        final GraphServiceClient graphClient = GraphServiceClient
                .builder()
                .authenticationProvider(auth)
                .buildClient();

        final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get();

        System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(me));

    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @AlfredoRevilla-MSFT , I am able to get msalAccessToken using MSAL Java library using certificate authentication. But as mentioned in your example above, my code fails at:         final User me = graphClient.me().buildRequest().get(); with certifciate related exception though I am using the same certficate using which i get msalAccessToken.  The exception is  "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".